# Spring Cloud Config Server and Client with RabbitMQ : Props not updated after git push

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, gitlab, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am running Spring Cloud Config Server and a Cloud Config Client in Pivotal Cloud Foundry .

1st version:
I can update client properties by pushing a YML file to a git repo. I did a POST on config-client/refresh and it updated successfully. I am connecting via HTTPS.

2nd version:
I am now trying to automatically push config updates with RabbitMQ. My Cloud Config Server successfully receives a gitlab webhook POST call to the config-server/monitor endpoint. Config Server sees the update and  sends a message to my Config Client.

However, the problem is that the client never updates its properties. I don't think it knows that any of its property files are updated. [ It may not know specifically what file was updated... ]

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with gitlab's webhooks ?

Thank you for any help.

Client log entries with app context reload highlighted. This happens after the code push:

```
2017-02-03T20:53:59.27-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-02-04 01:53:59.274  INFO 19 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.c.monitor.PropertyPathEndpoint     : Refresh for: *
2017-02-03T20:53:59.34-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-02-04 01:53:59.346  INFO 19 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : **Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext**
2017-02-03T20:53:59.35-0500 [APP/0]      OUT 2017-02-04 01:53:59.358  INFO 19 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3325da05: startup date [Sat Feb 04 01:53:59 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Seems you need the spring cloud bus support, please check this.

Comment: I think the bus is working. Messages are going from the server to the client.

Comment: Why are you importing the bus dependencies BOM?

Comment: And a milestone at that?

Comment: @JRB So you add the `@RefreshScope` to the client too, right?

Comment: Including the bus dependencies BOM was something that I saw in a tutorial. I've since removed it, with no change. @RefreshScope was already in the client.

Comment: There's a comment in this blog entry that the gitlab webhook doesn't send the files that changed. I think that's what I'm seeing here. So, how does one determine if a particular file changed ?  https://spencer.gibb.us/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/